# Sample Project has no Android Private Libraries, Android Dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, dependency-injection

[image]

libPinned~, Pinned~ project has no android libraries. (vs. PlusSample~ has)

So I cannot debug and run projects.

They does not have pom.xml (maybe is not maven...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing some project configuration files ... You could try [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject) to update your project from existing source. Assuming you have the Android tools and platform-tools in your Path, you could try the following command (from libPinnedXYZ):

```
android update project --name libPinnedXYZ --target 17 --path .
```

Then an Eclipse -> Clean should put you on track ...